# How to deploy selenium bot on cloud

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, automation, cloud

I have recently created an Instagram bot keeping in mind all the community guidelines which will make my insta bot hard to track. But in order to do that, I have to keep my PC on 24/7 which I can't. So I was thinking if there is a way through which I can deploy my bot on the server so it can run all the time.
I have made my bot on python and selenium.

Comment: What do you mean by "the bot can run all the time"? What are the actions done by this bot?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an instagram bot as well and am looking to make the same steps forward (running my python scripts on a vm). Have you tried using bash scripts that auto run at a certain time to run your scripts?  If you can get this to work on your local machine doing the same in the cloud wouldn't be hard at all. Let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: This should be comment not an answer

Comment: I'm not going to just give him the bash script that I wrote for my cloud deployment. If we are both competing in the same marketplace why would I spoon feed one of my competitors an answer. My ANSWER has more than enough information to lead you on 2 google searches to find the 7 bash lines you need to write lol.

Comment: Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer."

Comment: ^^ quote from the Stack Overflow how to answer guide. Maybe you should suggest your own complete solution to the question rather than feebly trying to troll someone offering help. Just a thought.